# How to write localStorage in a Redux app using middleware?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, middleware

I am creating an app which fetches the list of cities entered by a user and their respective weather using openweather API. I want the cities, as a result, to remain after I refresh the page. I know how to persist the data using browser localStorage API. But I don't know how to persist it through a middleware and pass it to the provider.

Below is my main Index.js file-:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import ReduxPromise from 'redux-promise';

import App from './components/app';
import reducers from './reducers';
import {loadState,saveState} from './localStorage';

const persistedState=loadState();
const store=createStore(persistedState);

store.subscribe(()=>{
store.getState()
});

const createStoreWithMiddleware =
     applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise)(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
<App />
</Provider>
, document.querySelector('.container-fluid'));
```

This is the localStorage.js file-:

```
export const loadState=()=>{
try{
    const serializedState=localStorage.getItem('state');
    if(serializedState===null){
        return undefined;
    }
    return JSON.parse(serializedState);
}catch(err){
    return undefined;
}
};

export const saveState=(state)=>{
try {
    const serializedState=JSON.stringify(state);
    localStorage.setItem('state',serializedState);
}catch(err){
    console.log(err);
}};
```

I have written the reducer in different files in reducers folder.

reducers/index.js -:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import WeatherReducer from './reducer_weather';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
weather:WeatherReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

and another reducer in 
    reducers/reducer_weather.js -:

```
import {FETCH_WEATHER} from '../actions/index';
import {DELETECITY} from '../actions/deleterow';
export default function(state=[],action){

switch(action.type){
    case FETCH_WEATHER:
        console.log([action.payload.data, ...state]);
        return [action.payload.data, ...state];
    case DELETECITY:
        console.log([...state].filter((weather)=>{
            return weather.city.id!==action.payload
        }));
        return [...state].filter((weather)=>{
            return weather.city.id!==action.payload
        });
    default:
        return state;

    }; 
}
```

Before using the localStorage for persisting the application state, my code was working fine. But now it is showing me an error. I am facing a problem regarding `const createStoreWithMiddleware =
     applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise)(createStore);`

how to use store using this middleware and how to pass in `<Provider>` tag's store property?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist).

> Persist and rehydrate a redux store

Using this middleware all the data you have in the Redux Store will be automatically persisted to the **localStorage** (different type of storage can be used too). Therefore, when you refresh a page, the already persisted data from the previous request will be automatically rehydrated (pushed) back to the Store.

---

## Example, taken from documentation:

**Configuration**:

```
// configureStore.js

import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage' // defaults to localStorage for web and AsyncStorage for react-native

import rootReducer from './reducers'

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

export default () => {
  let store = createStore(persistedReducer)
  let persistor = persistStore(store)
  return { store, persistor }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'

// ... normal setup, create store and persistor, import components etc.

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <RootComponent />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanx for your answer. but where do i use `createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)` in my main index.js file?

Comment: I want to provide the result in the store property of Provider tag. @JordanEnev

Comment: First of all, you don't pass the correct parameters to [createStore](https://redux.js.org/api/createstore) function. You should pass your reducers as first parameter, instead of passing the preloaded state. The preloaded state (`persistedState`) should be passed as second parameter.  Also I would recommend you to check [applyMiddleware](https://redux.js.org/api/applymiddleware) documentation and how you should use it.

Comment: However, I would suggest you to use `redux-persist`. It's easily configurable and it's exactly the same functionality you want. Just configure it to your project and you have localStorage persistance on the fly. Why don't you give it a try?